# Python , Gspread, Updating B1 if A1 is not Blank for Entire Column ( Loop & Ifs ? )

Tags: python, gspread

Pretty Noobish here, and after hard coding some stuff while trying to figure out loops, I decided there needs to be a more dynamic solution to my problem

I would like to have python go down the entire first column of a spreadsheet looking for any kind of value, let's say it is a list of names,

```
A1= Brian, 
A2= Dan 
A3 = Chris.
```

Then in the next column I want to perform an action.  To keep it simple while I am learning, I want to say

```
B1= Brian is here, 
B2 = Dan is here, 
B3 = Chris is here.
```

Seems simple enough but I am having trouble. Any advice or learning material would be great! Thanks in advance everyone!

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 0):

what you are looking for is a gspread method to get the entire column A of your sheet, then read each value and if the value matches some conditions (something like `value == "Brian"`) then update the cell on the same row in column B.

This could be achieved as follow:

```py
import gspread

# add more names to match and trigger condition
NAMES=["Brian", "Dan"]

client = gspread.service_account()
spsh = client.open("my spreadsheet")
sh = spsh.sheet1
column_a = sh.range("A1:A1000")
for cell in column_a:
  if cell.value in NAMES
    sh.update_cell(cell.row, cell.col + 1, "is here")
```

Comment: I got this working , this is a huge help! but I am only returning "is here" instead of "Brian is here"  would I use a concatenate after cell.col +1 ?

Comment: If you want to update the current cell with the name you do `sh.update_cell(cell.row, cell.col,  cell.value + " is here")`